# How to flush previous input on resuming activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have this app where when i enter some values in `editText` of 1st activity i.e `ActivityA` and then press a `Button` shows the result in next activity i.e `ActivityB`. But when i revert back to `ActivityA` and change some values and press button so that i want another `ActivityC` to be called, `ActivityB` only appears.

but if i restart my application and put values required to get `ActivityC` i will get it. how am i supposed solve this problem?

**EDIT :** 
**ActivityA**

```
 package com.example.iolcalci;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Selection extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener{
    private EditText k1_e,k2_e,al_e,alconst_e,dr_e;
    TextView k1_m,k2_m;
    private float k1,k2,al,al_const,dr,Avg_k,v_k1,v_k2,v_dr;
    private Float srkt_rnd,srk2_rnd,holladay_rnd,binkhorst_rnd,IOLPower_srkt,IOLPower_srk2,IOLPower_bink,IOLPower_holl;
    private float srkt_rf2,srkt_rf3,srkt_rf4,srkt_rf5,srkt_rf6,srkt_rf7,srkt_rf8,srkt_rf9,srkt_rf10,srkt_rf11,srkt_rf12;
    private float holladay_rf2,holladay_rf3,holladay_rf4,holladay_rf5,holladay_rf6,holladay_rf7,holladay_rf8,holladay_rf9,holladay_rf10,holladay_rf11,holladay_rf12;
    private float binkhorst_rf2,binkhorst_rf3,binkhorst_rf4,binkhorst_rf5,binkhorst_rf6,binkhorst_rf7,binkhorst_rf8,binkhorst_rf9,binkhorst_rf10,binkhorst_rf11,binkhorst_rf12; 
    private Spinner spin;
    private Button result;
    private int spinSelected=-1;
    int flag = 0;
    String k1_s,k2_s,al_s,al_const_s,dr_s;
    TextWatcher k1e,k2e,ale,dre;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selective);
    setupUI(findViewById(R.id.form_layout));


        spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.formulae);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                    long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                spinSelected=pos;

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                spinSelected=-1;
            }
        });


        dr_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dr_editText);
        k1_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.k1_editText);
        k2_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.K2_editText);
        al_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.al_editText);
        alconst_e=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.al_const_editText);
        k1_m=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.k1_metric);
        k2_m=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.k2_metric);



        dr_e.setText("0.0");

        dr_e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dr_s=dr_e.getText().toString();
                v_dr=Float.valueOf(dr_s);

            }
        });

        al_e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!hasFocus){
                    al_s = al_e.getText().toString();

                    int dotPos = -1;    

                    for (int i = 0; i < al_s.length(); i++) {
                        char c = al_s.charAt(i);
                        if (c == '.') {
                            dotPos = i;
                        }
                    }

                    if (dotPos == -1){
                        if(al_s.length()==0){
                            al_e.setText("0.00");
                        }else{
                            al_e.setText(al_s + ".00");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ( al_s.length() - dotPos == 1 ) {
                            al_e.setText(al_s + "00");
                        } else if ( al_s.length() - dotPos == 2 ) {
                            al_e.setText(al_s + "0");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        k1_e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(!hasFocus){
                    String k1_s = k1_e.getText().toString();

                    int dotPos = -1;    

                    for (int i = 0; i < k1_s.length(); i++) {
                        char c = k1_s.charAt(i);
                        if (c == '.') {
                            dotPos = i;
                        }
                    }

                    if (dotPos == -1){
                        if(k1_s.length()==0){
                            k1_e.setText("0.00");
                        }else{
                            k1_e.setText(k1_s + ".00");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ( k1_s.length() - dotPos == 1 ) {
                            k1_e.setText(k1_s + "00");
                        } else if ( k1_s.length() - dotPos == 2 ) {
                            k1_e.setText(k1_s + "0");
                        }
                    }
                }
                k1_s=k1_e.getText().toString().trim();
                k1_e.setText(String.format(k1_s,"##.00"));
                if(k1_s.length()!=0){
                    k1=Float.parseFloat(k1_s);
                v_k1=Float.valueOf(k1);
                Log.v("K1",""+v_k1);
                if((v_k1>=(float)5.63)&&(v_k1<=(float)11.25)){
                    k1_m.setText("mm");
                    Log.v("CHECK1", "success1" +v_k1);
                }else if((v_k1>=(float)30)&&(v_k1<=(float)60)){
                    k1_m.setText("D");
                    Log.v("CHECK1", "success1" +v_k1);
                }else{

                }
                }

            }
        });

        k2_e.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(!hasFocus){
                    String k2_s = k2_e.getText().toString();

                    int dotPos = -1;    

                    for (int i = 0; i < k2_s.length(); i++) {
                        char c = k2_s.charAt(i);
                        if (c == '.') {
                            dotPos = i;
                        }
                    }

                    if (dotPos == -1){
                        if(k2_s.length()==0){
                            k2_e.setText("0.00");
                        }else{
                            k2_e.setText(k2_s + ".00");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if ( k2_s.length() - dotPos == 1 ) {
                            k2_e.setText(k2_s + "00");
                        } else if ( k2_s.length() - dotPos == 2 ) {
                            k2_e.setText(k2_s + "0");
                        }
                    }
                }

                k2_s=k2_e.getText().toString().trim(); 
                if(k2_s.length()!=0){   
                    k2=Float.parseFloat(k2_s);
                v_k2=Float.valueOf(k2);
                Log.v("K2",""+v_k2);
                if((v_k2>=5.63)&&(v_k2<=11.25)){
                    k2_m.setText("mm");
                    Log.v("CHECK2", "success2" +v_k2);
                }else if((v_k2>=30)&&(v_k1<=60)){
                    k2_m.setText("D");
                    Log.v("CHECK2", "success2" +v_k2);
                }else{

                }
                }
            }
        });



        result=(Button)findViewById(R.id.result);
        result.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(dr_e.getText().toString().length()==0|al_e.getText().toString().length()==0|alconst_e.getText().toString().length()==0){
                    flag=1;
                }else{

                dr=Float.parseFloat(dr_e.getText().toString());
                al=Float.parseFloat(al_e.getText().toString());
                al_const=Float.parseFloat(alconst_e.getText().toString());
                k1=Float.parseFloat(k1_e.getText().toString().trim());
                k2=Float.parseFloat(k2_e.getText().toString().trim());

                }

                if((v_k1>=(float)5.63)&&(v_k1<=(float)11.25)){
                    k1=Round((float)(337.5/v_k1),2);            
                }
                if((v_k2>=(float)5.63)&&(v_k2<=(float)11.25)){
                    k2=Round((float)(337.5/v_k2),2);            
                }


                Avg_k=(k1+k2)/2;
                if(spinSelected==0){
                IOLPower_srkt=Srkt();
                if(flag!=1){
                Intent iSrkt=new Intent(Selection.this,Srkt.class);
                iSrkt.putExtra("RESULT", IOLPower_srkt);
                iSrkt.putExtra("DR", dr);
                iSrkt.putExtra("IOL", srkt_rnd);
                iSrkt.putExtra("REFER7", srkt_rf7);
                iSrkt.putExtra("REFER2", srkt_rf2);
                iSrkt.putExtra("REFER3", srkt_rf3);
                iSrkt.putExtra("REFER4", srkt_rf4);
                iSrkt.putExtra("REFER5", srkt_rf5);
                iSrkt.putExtra("REFER6", srkt_rf6);
                iSrkt.putExtra("REFER8", srkt_rf8);
                iSrkt.putExtra("REFER9", srkt_rf9);
                iSrkt.putExtra("REFER10", srkt_rf10);
                iSrkt.putExtra("REFER11", srkt_rf11);
                iSrkt.putExtra("REFER12", srkt_rf12);
                startActivity(iSrkt);
                }else{
                    Intent iSrktx=new Intent(Selection.this,Srkt_x.class);
                    startActivity(iSrktx);

                }

            }else if(spinSelected==1){
                IOLPower_bink=Binkhorst();

                if(flag!=1){
                    Intent iBinkhorst=new Intent(Selection.this,Binkhorst.class);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("RESULT", IOLPower_bink);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("DR", dr);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("IOL", binkhorst_rnd);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("REFER7", binkhorst_rf7);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("REFER2", binkhorst_rf2);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("REFER3", binkhorst_rf3);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("REFER4", binkhorst_rf4);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("REFER5", binkhorst_rf5);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("REFER6", binkhorst_rf6);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("REFER8", binkhorst_rf8);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("REFER9", binkhorst_rf9);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("REFER10", binkhorst_rf10);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("REFER11", binkhorst_rf11);
                    iBinkhorst.putExtra("REFER12", binkhorst_rf12);
                    startActivity(iBinkhorst);
                }else{
                    Intent iBinkhorstx=new Intent(Selection.this,Binkhorst_x.class);
                    startActivity(iBinkhorstx);
                }

            }else if(spinSelected==2){
            IOLPower_srk2=Srk2();
            if((Math.ceil(IOLPower_srk2)-IOLPower_srk2)>0.5){
                srk2_rnd=(float) Math.floor(IOLPower_srk2);
            }else{
                srk2_rnd=(float) Math.ceil(IOLPower_srk2);
            }

            if(flag!=1){
                Intent iSrk2=new Intent(Selection.this,Srk2.class);
                iSrk2.putExtra("RESULT", IOLPower_srk2);
                iSrk2.putExtra("DR", dr);
                iSrk2.putExtra("IOL", srk2_rnd);
                startActivity(iSrk2);
            }else{
                Intent iSrk2x=new Intent(Selection.this,Srk2_x.class);
                startActivity(iSrk2x);

            }

            }else{
                IOLPower_holl=Holladay();

                if(flag!=1){
                    Intent iHolladay=new Intent(Selection.this,Holladay.class);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("RESULT", IOLPower_holl);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("DR", dr);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("IOL", holladay_rnd);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("REFER7", holladay_rf7);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("REFER2", holladay_rf2);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("REFER3", holladay_rf3);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("REFER4", holladay_rf4);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("REFER5", holladay_rf5);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("REFER6", holladay_rf6);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("REFER8", holladay_rf8);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("REFER9", holladay_rf9);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("REFER10", holladay_rf10);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("REFER11", holladay_rf11);
                    iHolladay.putExtra("REFER12", holladay_rf12);
                    startActivity(iHolladay);
                }else{
                    Intent iHolladayx=new Intent(Selection.this,Holladay_x.class);
                    startActivity(iHolladayx);
                }

            }
            }
            });
        Button reset=(Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dr_e.setText("0.0");
                al_e.setText("");
                k1_e.setText("");
                k2_e.setText("");
                alconst_e.setText("");
                dr_e.requestFocus();
            }
        });

}
    public static float Round(float Rval, int Rpl) {
          float p = (float)Math.pow(10,Rpl);
          Rval = Rval * p;
          float tmp = Math.round(Rval);
          return (float)tmp/p;
          }
    public float Srkt(){
         float Rcor;
         float Lcor;
         float Crwdest;
         float Corneal_H;
         float Acd_Const;
         float Offset;
         float Acd_Est;
         float Na=(float) 1.336;
         float C2=(float) 0.3333;
         float C3;
         float C4;
         float C5;
         float C6;
         float C8;
         float C9;
         float Iolam;


         float Rcor1=(float)(337.5/Avg_k);Rcor=Round(Rcor1,2);

            if(al<=24.2){
                Lcor=al;
            }else{
                Lcor=(float) (-3.446+1.716*al-0.0237*(al*al));
            }Lcor=Round(Lcor,2);
            Crwdest=(float) (-5.41+0.58412*Lcor+0.098*Avg_k);Crwdest=Round(Crwdest,2);
            Corneal_H=(float) (Rcor-(Math.sqrt(Rcor*Rcor-Crwdest*Crwdest/4)));Corneal_H=Round(Corneal_H,2);
            Acd_Const=(float) (0.62467*al_const-68.747);
            Offset=(float) (Acd_Const-3.336);Offset=Round(Offset,2);
            Acd_Est=(Corneal_H+Offset); float Acd_Est1=Round(Acd_Est,2);
            C3=(float) (0.97971*al+0.65696);C3=Round(C3,2);     
            C4=C3-Acd_Est1;C4=Round(C4,2);
            C5=(float) ((Na*Rcor)-(C2*Acd_Est)); C5=Round(C5, 2);
            C6=(float) ((Na*Rcor1)-(C2*C3));
            C8=(float) ((12*C6)+(C3*Rcor1));C8=Round(C8,2);
            C9=(float) ((12*C5)+(Acd_Est*Rcor1));C9=Round(C9,2);
            Iolam=(float) ((1336*(C6-(0.001*C8*dr)))/(C4*(C5-(0.001*dr*C9))));Iolam=Round(Iolam,2);
            if((Math.ceil(Iolam)-Iolam)>0.5){
                srkt_rnd=(float) Math.floor(Iolam);
            }else{
                srkt_rnd=(float) Math.ceil(Iolam);
            }
            srkt_rf7=(float) (((1336*C6)-(srkt_rnd*C4*C5))/((1.336*C8)-(0.001*srkt_rnd*C4*C9)));
            srkt_rf6=(float) (((1336*C6)-((srkt_rnd+0.5)*C4*C5))/((1.336*C8)-(0.001*(srkt_rnd+0.5)*C4*C9)));
            srkt_rf5=(float) (((1336*C6)-((srkt_rnd+1)*C4*C5))/((1.336*C8)-(0.001*(srkt_rnd+1)*C4*C9)));
            srkt_rf4=(float) (((1336*C6)-((srkt_rnd+1.5)*C4*C5))/((1.336*C8)-(0.001*(srkt_rnd+1.5)*C4*C9)));
            srkt_rf3=(float) (((1336*C6)-((srkt_rnd+2)*C4*C5))/((1.336*C8)-(0.001*(srkt_rnd+2)*C4*C9)));
            srkt_rf2=(float) (((1336*C6)-((srkt_rnd+2.5)*C4*C5))/((1.336*C8)-(0.001*(srkt_rnd+2.5)*C4*C9)));
            srkt_rf8=(float) (((1336*C6)-((srkt_rnd-0.5)*C4*C5))/((1.336*C8)-(0.001*(srkt_rnd-0.5)*C4*C9)));
            srkt_rf9=(float) (((1336*C6)-((srkt_rnd-1)*C4*C5))/((1.336*C8)-(0.001*(srkt_rnd-1)*C4*C9)));
            srkt_rf10=(float) (((1336*C6)-((srkt_rnd-1.5)*C4*C5))/((1.336*C8)-(0.001*(srkt_rnd-1.5)*C4*C9)));
            srkt_rf11=(float) (((1336*C6)-((srkt_rnd-2)*C4*C5))/((1.336*C8)-(0.001*(srkt_rnd-2)*C4*C9)));
            srkt_rf12=(float) (((1336*C6)-((srkt_rnd-2.5)*C4*C5))/((1.336*C8)-(0.001*(srkt_rnd-2.5)*C4*C9)));

        return(Iolam);
    }
    public float Binkhorst(){
        float K1;
        float LB2;
        float ACDbnk;
        float xb;
        float yb;
        float em;

        K1=(float)(337.5/Avg_k);
        LB2=(float) (al+0.1984);
        if(LB2>=26){
            ACDbnk=(float) (((0.58357*al_const)-63.896)*1.1087);
        }else{
            ACDbnk=(float) (((0.58357*al_const)-63.896)*LB2/23.45);
        }
        xb=(float) (1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2)-0.001*dr*(16.032*K1-4*LB2+LB2*K1)));
        yb=(float) ((LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk-0.001*dr*(16.032*K1-4*ACDbnk+ACDbnk*K1)));
        em=xb/yb;em=Round(em,2);
        if((Math.ceil(em)-em)>0.5){
            binkhorst_rnd=(float) Math.floor(em);
        }else{
            binkhorst_rnd=(float) Math.ceil(em);
        }
        binkhorst_rf7=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2))-binkhorst_rnd*(LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*LB2)+(LB2*K1))-0.001*binkhorst_rnd*(LB2-ACDbnk)*((16.032*K1)-(4*ACDbnk)+(ACDbnk*K1))));
        binkhorst_rf6=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2))-(binkhorst_rnd+0.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*LB2)+(LB2*K1))-0.001*(binkhorst_rnd+0.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*((16.032*K1)-(4*ACDbnk)+(ACDbnk*K1))));
        binkhorst_rf5=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2))-(binkhorst_rnd+1)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*LB2)+(LB2*K1))-0.001*(binkhorst_rnd+1)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*((16.032*K1)-(4*ACDbnk)+(ACDbnk*K1))));
        binkhorst_rf4=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2))-(binkhorst_rnd+1.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*LB2)+(LB2*K1))-0.001*(binkhorst_rnd+1.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*((16.032*K1)-(4*ACDbnk)+(ACDbnk*K1))));
        binkhorst_rf3=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2))-(binkhorst_rnd+2)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*LB2)+(LB2*K1))-0.001*(binkhorst_rnd+2)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*((16.032*K1)-(4*ACDbnk)+(ACDbnk*K1))));
        binkhorst_rf2=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2))-(binkhorst_rnd+2.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*LB2)+(LB2*K1))-0.001*(binkhorst_rnd+2.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*((16.032*K1)-(4*ACDbnk)+(ACDbnk*K1))));
        binkhorst_rf8=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2))-(binkhorst_rnd-0.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*LB2)+(LB2*K1))-0.001*(binkhorst_rnd-0.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*((16.032*K1)-(4*ACDbnk)+(ACDbnk*K1))));
        binkhorst_rf9=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2))-(binkhorst_rnd-1)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*LB2)+(LB2*K1))-0.001*(binkhorst_rnd-1)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*((16.032*K1)-(4*ACDbnk)+(ACDbnk*K1))));
        binkhorst_rf10=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2))-(binkhorst_rnd-1.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*LB2)+(LB2*K1))-0.001*(binkhorst_rnd-1.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*((16.032*K1)-(4*ACDbnk)+(ACDbnk*K1))));
        binkhorst_rf11=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2))-(binkhorst_rnd-2)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*LB2)+(LB2*K1))-0.001*(binkhorst_rnd-2)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*((16.032*K1)-(4*ACDbnk)+(ACDbnk*K1))));
        binkhorst_rf12=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*LB2))-(binkhorst_rnd-2.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*ACDbnk))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*LB2)+(LB2*K1))-0.001*(binkhorst_rnd-2.5)*(LB2-ACDbnk)*((16.032*K1)-(4*ACDbnk)+(ACDbnk*K1))));


        return(em);
    }
    public float Srk2(){
        float X25 = 0;
        float Avg_k=(k1+k2)/2;
        if(al<20.0){
            X25=al_const+3;
        }else if((al>=20.0)&&(al<21.0)){
            X25=al_const+2;
        }else if((al>=21.0)&&(al<22.0)){
            X25=al_const+1;
        }else if((al>=22.0)&&(al<24.5)){
            X25=al_const;
        }else if(al>=24.5){
            X25=(float) (al_const-(0.5));
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter valid AL value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        float SRK2 = (float) (X25-(0.9*Avg_k+2.5*al));
        return(SRK2);
    }
    public float Holladay(){
        float K;
        float Lhol;
        float SF;
        float Rag;
        float AGx;
        float AG;
        float ACDH;
        float CAhol;
        float xh;
        float yh;

        float K1=(float)(337.5/Avg_k);K=Round(K1,2);
        Lhol=(float) (al+0.2);
        SF=(float) ((0.5663*al_const)-65.6);
        if(K<7){
            Rag=7;
        }else{
            Rag=K;
        }
        AGx=(float) (al*0.533);
        if(AGx>13.5){
             AG=(float) 13.5;
        }else{
            AG=AGx;
        }
        ACDH=(float) (0.56+Rag-(Math.sqrt(Rag*Rag-AG*AG/4)));
        CAhol=ACDH+SF;
        xh=(float) (1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol)-0.001*dr*(16.032*K1-4*Lhol+Lhol*K1)));
        yh=(float) ((Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol-0.001*dr*(16.032*K1-4*CAhol+CAhol*K1)));
        float em=xh/yh;em=Round(em,2);
        if((Math.ceil(em)-em)>0.5){
            holladay_rnd=(float) Math.floor(em);
        }else{
            holladay_rnd=(float) Math.ceil(em);
        }

        holladay_rf7=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol))-holladay_rnd*(Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*Lhol)+(Lhol*K1))-0.001*holladay_rnd*(Lhol-CAhol)*((16.032*K1)-(4*CAhol)+(CAhol*K1))));
        holladay_rf6=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol))-(holladay_rnd+0.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*Lhol)+(Lhol*K1))-0.001*(holladay_rnd+0.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*((16.032*K1)-(4*CAhol)+(CAhol*K1))));
        holladay_rf5=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol))-(holladay_rnd+1)*(Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*Lhol)+(Lhol*K1))-0.001*(holladay_rnd+1)*(Lhol-CAhol)*((16.032*K1)-(4*CAhol)+(CAhol*K1))));
        holladay_rf4=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol))-(holladay_rnd+1.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*Lhol)+(Lhol*K1))-0.001*(holladay_rnd+1.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*((16.032*K1)-(4*CAhol)+(CAhol*K1))));
        holladay_rf3=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol))-(holladay_rnd+2)*(Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*Lhol)+(Lhol*K1))-0.001*(holladay_rnd+2)*(Lhol-CAhol)*((16.032*K1)-(4*CAhol)+(CAhol*K1))));
        holladay_rf2=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol))-(holladay_rnd+2.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*Lhol)+(Lhol*K1))-0.001*(holladay_rnd+2.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*((16.032*K1)-(4*CAhol)+(CAhol*K1))));
        holladay_rf8=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol))-(holladay_rnd-0.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*Lhol)+(Lhol*K1))-0.001*(holladay_rnd-0.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*((16.032*K1)-(4*CAhol)+(CAhol*K1))));
        holladay_rf9=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol))-(holladay_rnd-1)*(Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*Lhol)+(Lhol*K1))-0.001*(holladay_rnd-1)*(Lhol-CAhol)*((16.032*K1)-(4*CAhol)+(CAhol*K1))));
        holladay_rf10=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol))-(holladay_rnd-1.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*Lhol)+(Lhol*K1))-0.001*(holladay_rnd-1.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*((16.032*K1)-(4*CAhol)+(CAhol*K1))));
        holladay_rf11=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol))-(holladay_rnd-2.0)*(Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*Lhol)+(Lhol*K1))-0.001*(holladay_rnd-2)*(Lhol-CAhol)*((16.032*K1)-(4*CAhol)+(CAhol*K1))));
        holladay_rf12=(float) ((1336*((1.336*K1-0.3333*Lhol))-(holladay_rnd-2.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*(1.336*K1-0.3333*CAhol))/(1.336*((16.032*K1)-(4*Lhol)+(Lhol*K1))-0.001*(holladay_rnd-2.5)*(Lhol-CAhol)*((16.032*K1)-(4*CAhol)+(CAhol*K1))));

        return(em);
    }


    //when the back button is pressed from next activity
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        dr_e.requestFocus();

    }
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    public void setupUI(View view) {

        //Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
        if(!(view instanceof EditText)) {

            view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    hideSoftKeyboard(Selection.this);
                    return false;
                }

            });
        }

        //If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {

            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {

                View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);

                setupUI(innerView);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

---

**ActivityB**

```
    package com.example.iolcalci;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Srk2 extends Activity {
    private Float Result,dr,Srk2_rnd7,Srk2_rnd2,Srk2_rnd3,Srk2_rnd4,Srk2_rnd5,Srk2_rnd6,Srk2_rnd8,Srk2_rnd9,Srk2_rnd10,Srk2_rnd11,Srk2_rnd12;
    private Float Ref2,Ref3,Ref4,Ref5,Ref6,Ref7,Ref8,Ref9,Ref10,Ref11,Ref12;
    private float Rf;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_srk2);
        Thread srk2=new Thread(){
            public void run() { 

            TextView power=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.srk2_power);
            TextView name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.iolpower);
            Result=getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("RESULT");
            dr=getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("DR");
            if(dr==0){
                name.setText("EM  :");
            }else{
                name.setText("AM  :");
            }
            Srk2_rnd7=getIntent().getExtras().getFloat("IOL");

            power.setText(String.valueOf(Result));

        //some more calculation


            }
            };
            srk2.start();
    }
    public float refraction(Float ans){
        Rf=refer();
        return((Result-ans)/Rf);
    }
    public float refer(){
        float Refer;
        if(Result>14){
            Refer=(float) 1.25;
        }else{
            Refer=1;
        }
        return(Refer);
    }

}
```

---

**ActivityC**

```
    package com.example.iolcalci;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Srk2_x extends Activity
{
    Float result;
      @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_srk2_x);
          TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.srk2_power);
          text.setText("INVALID");

  }
}
```

Comment: "How am i supposed solve this problem?" - If you don't provide code - yourself.

Comment: @DmytroDanylyk i have just implemented oncreate in activity

Comment: VERY LESS DETAIL YOU HAVE PORVIDED

Comment: @BhaveshJethani see the edited version.. please do not down vote

Comment: @DmytroDanylyk any idea?

Answer (score 0):

By maintaining visited activity Queue or use Activity stack to track the activity sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the `flag` value is controlling which activity to start. I guess you should change `flag` to default value when you start a new activity, or override [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) method in your activity and change it there.